# Foreach Item in listbox

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a listbox `Listbox1` that displays a list of ZoneID's

I want to set a variable and execute a stored procedure for each of these ZoneID's. I have been testing this by displaying a message box with each ZoneID, but all I can get to show in the message box is "ZoneID"

```
private void Btn_AddModel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString())) {
    List <Zone> Zonelist = conn.Query<Zone>("GetZone", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Zone>();

    listBox1.DataSource = Zonelist;
    listBox1.ValueMember = "ZoneID";
  }

  DisplayMessageBoxForEach();
}


private void DisplayMessageBoxForEach() {
  foreach(object ValueMember in listBox1.Items) {
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.ValueMember.ToString());
  }
}
```

I am guessing I am missing some simple syntax but its all new to me. I could also do without having the listbox and use the DapperList but again, it's all new to me.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

`ValueMember` is just a property that defines which property is being used in your DataSource.

Your looping should look something like this:

```
foreach(Zone zone in (List<Zone>)listBox1.DataSource) {
  MessageBox.Show(zone.ToString());
}
```

Replace the `ToString()` with whatever property you want to display from the Zone class.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in foreach loop:

```
Zone objZone = (Zone) ValueMember:

MessageBox.Show(objZone.ZoneID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forgoing dapper and writing out the SQL command in the application to a list, Found it much easier to complete the job. Working now. Thank you !

```
conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ZoneID from Zones", conn);
                    SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<int> zoneIDs = new List<int>();
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            zoneIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(myReader["ZoneID"]));
                        }
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        myReader.Close();

                        foreach (int zones in zoneIDs)
                        {

                            int Zone_ID = zones;
                        }
```